# convertendo números em formato de horas Select Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estou precisando fazer um relatório de controle de ponto para minha empresa, a situação é a seguinte.
Tenho a tabela `TGFPON` que registra a marcação de ponto dos funcionários que tem esse `desc`.

```
desc TFPPON

ENTRADA     NOT NULL NUMBER(5)   
SAIDA       NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
```

Quando é feito o armazenamento dos registro na coluna ENTRADA os números ficam assim: `1330` que no caso seria `13:30`. 
Como que eu posso fazer um `select` que mostra os dados no formato de hora `13:30` ?

Obrigado !

Comment: select substr( entrada, 1,2 ) || ':' || substr( entrada, 3,2 ) from tabela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Como que eu posso fazer um select que mostra os dados no formato de
>   hora 13:30?

Como você já possui os valores existentes no banco e **garante** que eles sejam apenas de 4 digitos numéricos no formato de `hh:mm` e quer apenas retorná-los com o separador de horas `:`, você pode realizar a *query* abaixo:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ENTRADA, 0, 2) || ':' || SUBSTR(ENTRADA, 3, 2) AS ENTRADA, 
         SUBSTR(SAIDA, 0, 2) || ':' || SUBSTR(SAIDA, 3, 2) AS SAIDA
 FROM sua_tabela
```

1. O comando `SUBSTR(entrada, posicaoo, [tamanho_entrada])`, que nos retorna uma fatia do parâmetro de entrada, neste caso sendo os 2 primeiros digitos.
2. O comando `||` é responsável por concatenar strings no Oracle, mas você pode usar também o [CONCAT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php).

Apesar de solucionar seu problema, aconselho trabalhar com o data_type `DATE` já que seu objetivo é trabalhar com o controle de ponto de sua empresa, sendo assim seria uma maneira mais segura e completa de se trabalhar os pontos de seus funcionários.

[Trabalhar com data e hora no oracle](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-data-e-hora-no-oracle/6985) é facil e você pode encontrar diversos exemplos na internet.

Answer (score 3):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(lpad(to_char(ENTRADA),4,'0'), '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '\1:\2')
from TFPPON;
```

- `to_char` - converte o numero para texto
- `lpad` - acrescenta o 0  até completar 4 numeros para os casos como `07:00` que estaria salvo como `700`
- `REGEXP_REPLACE` - formata o código utilizando regex

Veja exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7feccd/8

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado !